# Null Pointer Exception on LiveData using Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have an app that fetchs data from API using retrofit with coroutines. (Deferred)

I´m trying to implement a Room cache database for this, but I´ve just tried to use LiveData to fetch the data from Repository (not success). Tried to .alowMainThreadQueries (not success).
The message is:

```
Attempt to invoke...... on a null object reference.
```

The main problem is: When i launch the App again, it fetches the data from the database and displays it correctly.

What am i doing wrong?
This is my DAO

```
@Dao
interface VarietiesDao{

    @Query("select * from pokevariationsentity where id = :id")
    fun getVariety(id: Int): LiveData<PokeVariationsEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(pokes: PokeVariationsEntity) // will pass the pokes
}

private lateinit var INSTANCE : PokeVarietiesDatabase

fun getVarietiesDatabase(context: Context): PokeVarietiesDatabase {
    synchronized(PokeVarietiesDatabase::class.java){
        if(!::INSTANCE.isInitialized){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                PokeVarietiesDatabase::class.java,
                "odaps2l.db").build() // name
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE
}
```

Repo:

```
 class VarietiesRepositoryImpl(private val database: PokeVarietiesDatabase, private val id: String) {


   val varieties: LiveData<PokeVariety>
        get() = Transformations.map(database.varietiesDao.getVariety(Integer.parseInt(id))){
           it.asDomainModelFromVariations()
        }

    suspend fun refreshVarieties(id: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val pokeList = PokeApi.retrofitService.getVariations(Integer.parseInt(id)).await()
            database.varietiesDao.insertAll(pokeList.asDatabaseModel())
        }
    }
}
```

Actually i thought that the problem was the TypeConverter, but once it runs okay on the second time, that´s i realized that is nothing about it.

**UPDATE**

I just alowed .aloMainThreadQueries
and tried to do it as Sync mode. returning an Object instead of LiveData.
Surrounded the message Parameter specified as non-null is null: method

```
`kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter $this$asDomainModelFromVariations`
```

At the first time I click on the item, and the second time it Loads perfectly. The Same happens with livedata.

Comment: May be MediatorLiveData should be used instead of LiveData. This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136438/android-livedata-and-room-getvalue-returning-null?rq=1

Comment: I've just changed the main post!  Same problem :/

Comment: You may have missed a `?` in the method signature. Just see all the duplicates ...

Comment: The problem was a simple '?' on some places... thank you so much @MartinZeitler